# Passing variables and keeping them hidden

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a blog using MVC 4 and right now I am having problems sending the postid to the comment create page and keeping it hidden until I hit create to create the comment with the post id

**This is the comment create view**

```
@model MVCProjectApp.Models.Comment

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Comment";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Comments</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Timestamp)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Timestamp)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Timestamp)
        </div>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "~/FullPost/Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**This is the Actionlink where I am passing the postid to the comment create**

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Comment", "Create", "Comment", ID, null)
```

**This is the comment controller**

```
 //
        // GET: /Comment/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.PostID = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostID", "Title");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Comment/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Comment comment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Comments.Add(comment);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.PostID = new SelectList(db.Posts, "PostID", "Title", comment.PostID);
            return View(comment);
        }
```

**This is the comment model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCProjectApp.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
    public class Comment
    {
        public int CommentID { get; set; }
        public int PostID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want it hidden? This seems to be pretty important information IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Use Html.HiddenFor() (as mentioned in the comments above) to hold values that you need to have returned to you from the view but do not want to display.

Keep in mind that this is hackable.  Take appropriate measures to ensure the ID you passed to the view is the same one that comes back.  Look up AntiForgeryToken.

Comment: I run into an error that says {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint\"FK_dbo.Comments_dbo.Posts_PostID\".The Confliect occurred in database \"MVCProjectApp.Models.DBPostsContext\",table\"dbo.Posts\",column 'PostID'.\r\nThe statement hasbeen terminated."} I am lost and not sure what to do